# Vaadin Charts not Drawing

Tags: highcharts, vaadin, vaadin-charts

I find myself in a bit of a pickle.

I am using the Vaadin Charts addon in Vaadin Touchkit (for a mobile application ofcorse) and I am using Xamerin to develop a hybrid application for both Andriod and iPhone/iPad.

The problem is that I have a Gauge(Vaadin Chart Gauge) that does not display on the iOS platforms, this is unusual behavior so instead of posting code I would like a proposed solution with the following constraints:

- The Chart object has to be a Vaadin Charts Gauge
- The Gauge drawing has to be 360 deg. (A circle)
- The Gauge should have 40 plot points that are clickable
- Each Y-Axis on the Gauge should be displayed (pie chart style)

[Sketch of Vaadin Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOpW0.jpg)

All help would be much appreciated, and if you do need to see what I have done thus far in code I will be more than happy to update this post.

On a side note, the chart does display if the user rotates the screen and then returns it to its original position.

Comment: What have your tried? Could you post a live example?

Comment: I figured out the solution this the chart didn't behave nicely with a responsive width. upon further investigation it could only cater for a minimum width of 338px anything less than that and the calender would not plot its y axis. Although this could have been project specific.